# Inductance of Two Primaries in Parallel

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply

I need to verify the design of a prototype SMPS transformer. The transformer has two primary windings driven in parallel specced at the same inductance value (the transformer manufacturer suggested this, our initial handwound design used a single primary). When I measure each primary separately, I read a value of 5 mH for both but when I connect the two in parallel, I still read 5 mH when I expect to read 2.5 mH. I measure the inductance with the secondary open circuit.

Is this expected, does the inductance not change because the windings share the same core?

This is the schematic for the design.

[image: Transformer Design Schematic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *does the inductance not change because the windings share the same
> core?*

Correct, two identical coils wound on the same core, when paralleled exhibit the same inductance as one coil. Think about winding an inductor with Litz wire. Litz wire is tens to thousands of very thin individually insulated wires that behave like a single fat wire (but better): -

[image]

Image from [here](http://e-magnetica.pl/litz_wire)

<sub>But, if the two coils did not share the same magnetic core then sure, the inductance would halve.</sub>

Maybe think about half the current going down one side of the wire in the coil and, the other half of the current going down the other side. Then, as brain experiment consider that the two sides of the wire are magically insulated from each other by a very thin gap running the length of the wire. That's the same as two wires.

Another way of looking at it is this: when two electrically connected 5 mH inductors get magnetically close to each other, both inductances rise towards 10 mH hence, their parallel arrangement becomes 5 mH.

This is based on the definition of inductance; the inductance is the amount of magnetic flux produced per amp.

So, both are producing an amount of flux when separated but, when together, not only is there the flux from each other but also the individual fluxes to consider hence, either coil appears to produce twice the flux for the same current therefore, inductance appears to double.

Comment: Do you know of any good textbooks for transformer design (a focus on SMPS would be nice). My lack of knowledge of transformers is frustrating at times =b

Comment: Everything I know is in my head, sorry.

Comment: @ElliottWinsted "Soft Ferrites" by Snelling and "Ferrites for Inductors and Transformers" by Snelling & Giles are two good books covering the basics. You'll find that magnetics is a complicated study. Uni libraries usually have these books.

Comment: That bottom explanation makes sense, I was not understanding why it seemed the primaries were "violating" the equation of inductors in parallel. I should have revisited *what is inductance* fundamentally to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

> when I connect the two in parallel, I still read 5 mH

That still just one winding with thicker wire :). Think about it for a second - try to come up with an explanation for a different outcome, e.g. halving of inductance.

The test you wanted to do (but didn't) is to connect the *two* primaries in **series** and get inductance *four* times higher. That's when the number of turns actually changes. Inductance is proportional to the square of the number of turns, so connecting two identical windings in series in-phase quadruples the inductance. Connecting them in anti-phase will lower the inductance by order of magnitude or more - depending on how close to ideal the windings and the magnetic path are.

Connecting the windings in anti-phase in parallel won't give very meaningful results, since the leakage inductance is canceled, while there's still good coupling between them, so it'll be like having a shorted secondary - only it's called primary.